# Change Background color of SnackBar in LaunchedEffect (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

I am trying to pass message from viewModel into my Screen Activity using collect in Android Jetpack compose, where I am trying to show snackbar but for some reason it is not changing background color and action button color (nor going in if condition) on snackbar and also it is not comparing to my string which I am passing and going in else condition always. Please advice how to handle this scenerio from Activity Screen

```
// From ViewModel

private val _showMessage = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
val showMessage get() = _showMessage.asSharedFlow()
_showMessage.emit("My custom message")


// From ViewController Activity

val scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

SnackbarHost(scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) { data ->
    // custom snackbar with the custom colors
    Snackbar(
        actionColor = Color.Blue,
        backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
    )
}

LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) {
    viewModel.showMessage.collect {
        if (viewModel.showMessage.equals(“My custom message”)) {
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(it, "OK", SnackbarDuration.Indefinite)
        } else {
            println("view message ${viewModel.showMessage.equals("My custom message”)}”).  /// Coming as false always
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `viewModel.showMessage` is a `SharedFlow<String>` not a `String`.

You are collecting String you can do operations with it naming parameter or using as `it`.

```
LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) {
    viewModel.showMessage.collect { message: String ->
        if (message == "My custom message") {
        
        }

}
```

Comment: I am more of looking to change background color of Snakbar but thank you for suggestion for collecting it from Mutable shared flow to show correct snakbar, do you have any suggesstion to change background color of Snakbar as for some reason mine is not reflecting correctly

Answer (score 1):

Add `containerColor` to your snackbar to change background color of snackbar

Example:

```
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) { data ->
        Snackbar(
            snackbarData = data,
            containerColor = Color.Red // For changing snackbar background color 
        )
    }
```